# Trying to use a number with percentage as value

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

Hi there I am trying to run a loop that changes the value of all cells containing 0% to value "N/A". I wrote the following code:

```
Dim Fail As Integer
Fail = "0%"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Activate
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    For X = 22 To LastRow

    If Range("G" & X).Value = Fail Then Range("G" & X).Value = "N/A"
Next X
```

but all it does is that it replaces all the values in column G with "N/A". Where did I go wrong?

Comment: `Dim Fail as Integer` should be `Dim Fail as String`, you can't use an Integer to display a character like %.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I tested it now but when running the code with String declaration nothing happens, no values changed.

Comment: Ah nevermind, I took out the quotation marks from the declaration and typed just 0 and now it works like a charm. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Alright, I think I know where the problem lies, the formatting is automatically changed to Percentage. So remove "%" from `Fail = "0%"` so it becomes `Fail = "0"`, you can also change the `Dim Fail As String` back to `Dim Fail As Integer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character "%" can't exist within an integer. You can only use whole numbers when dimming an integer. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)

Your problem lies within `Fail = "0%"`, excel automatically changes the formatting of all cells containing % to percentage. So what you need to do is to change `Fail = "0%"` to `Fail = "0"`.

See the final code below:

```
Dim Fail As Integer
Fail = "0"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Activate
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    For X = 22 To LastRow

    If Range("G" & X).Value = Fail Then Range("G" & X).Value = "N/A"
Next X
```

Answer (score 2):

Use simple replace statement on your range.

```
Worksheets("Summary").Range("G22:G1000").Replace What:="0%", Replacement:="NA"
```

Comment: This is by far the best solution to the problem. Funnily enough after 1 year of VBA experience,  I didn't know about this. Thank you!

Comment: @EliasWick Thanks for the comment.